# Почему в новую переменную передается указатель на основную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
supp_pack_delay = self.packets[packIndex]
supp_pack_delay['delayTime'] += delayed_time_harq
self.packets.insert(pack, supp_pack_delay)
```

Вкратце, создаю вспомогательную переменную, чтобы не менять значение основной по текущему индексу, затем перемещаю ее чуть дальше по ключу 'delayTime'. 
В итоге, при прибавлении supp_pack_delay['delayTime'] += delayed_time_harq основной массив (self.packets) тоже меняет свое значение.
Почему так происходит?
Состоит лист self.packets из

```
[{'bearerType': 1, 'identity': 82, 'userId': 0, 'size': 160, 'arrivalTime': 2, 'delayTime': 2,....},{'bearerType': 6, 'identity': 0, 'userId': 0, 'size': 1711, 'arrivalTime': 3, 'delayTime': 3,....},и т.д.]
```

Когда я закидываю значение первого элемента в переменную supp_pack_delay и меняю ее там, то получается в основном массиве это:

```
[{'bearerType': 1, 'identity': 82, 'userId': 0, 'size': 160, 'arrivalTime': 2, 'delayTime': 7,....},n{'bearerType': 6, 'identity': 0, 'userId': 0, 'size': 1711, 'arrivalTime': 3, 'delayTime': 3,....}, ..... {'bearerType': 1, 'identity': 82, 'userId': 0, 'size': 160, 'arrivalTime': 2, 'delayTime': 7,....}, ....]
```

Через insert элемент копируется на другую позицию, но почему-то первый тоже изменил поле 'delayTime'.

Comment: как вы себе представляете решение этой проблемы? "я что то куда то прибавил, почему то к этому прибавленное после того стало вот этим" - конкретизируйте, что было в переменных и что стало после

Comment: Добавил подробнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что python копирует ссылки на элементы, а не само значение.
Чтобы это исправить нужно сделать так:

```
from copy import deepcopy 
new_var = deepcopy (old_var)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это поможет вам решить проблему

```py
a  = [1, 2, 3]
a_ = [1, 2, 3]

b  = a
b_ = a_.copy()

b[0]  += 2
b_[0] += 2

print(a, a_)
```

Результат:

```
[3, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

Обращаю внимание на то, что `copy()` создаёт новый список, а не копирует ссылку на старый, но если внутри старого списка были ссылки на другие объекты - они будут перемещены именно как ссылки.
Т.е. если внутри списка есть другие списки, то вот в них значения всё равно будут изменяться.
Если вам нужно создать полностью автономную копию элемента, можно воспользоваться модулем `copy`:

```py
import copy
a = [1, [1, 2, 3], 3]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!